# Azure DevOps REST API - Create PR with Reviewer

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to create programmatically pull request in Azure DevOps from dotnet. It works fine, however when I try to create it with reviewer I stuck.

The request looks like this:

Calling `POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=7.2-preview.1`

With body:

```
"sourceRefName":"refs/heads/source",
"targetRefName":"refs/heads/target",
"title":"title of ticket",
"description":"Ticket summary",
"reviewers":[
    {
        "id":"0e464eb9-6389-4708-bc75-c4bb15877a9e"
    }
]
```

For the id I use `GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.2-preview.1`

Use the items/users/originId value from there.

Response for the PR is Bad Request?

```
Detailed message: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Invalid argument value.\r\nParameter name: A valid reviewer must be supplied.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer.InvalidArgumentValueException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebServer","typeKey":"InvalidArgumentValueException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

I tried several ids of the user (descriptor, originId from graph endpoint) and all gives back `The identity (no guid supplied) is not recognized.`

The user entitlement id works however the error message above prevents me to create the PR. The approver is in the project's team and has contributor access.

Is it possible to create a new PR with reviewers? If so, how? (I know that there is a PUT/PATCH endpoint but that adds or updates reviewers for an already existing PR and for me it is not the use case). Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. There is another id of course. So you have to provide the value of items/id. That would do the job.